# Java calculation issue

Tags: java

I am stuck on an issue described below

Suppose we have a string like `42932-5`, which has 6 numbers

I want to calculate the **total sum** as

```
4*6+2*5+9*4+3*3+2*2
```

How do we do this in Java?

Comment: How are you deriving your "total sum" formula...?

Comment: @Derek Seems to be a simple checksum for bill payment account numbers (looks like a Swedish one) with a decreasing multiplier towards the right. num(charAt(i))*(n-i)

Comment: Hello All
It an algorithm which I'm trying to invoke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say this efficent, I'm sure there's a better way to go about it, but hay, it was fun :P

The first thing you need to do is discard the parts of the `String` you don't need

```
int sum = 0;
String test = "42932-5";
List<Integer> listValues = new ArrayList<Integer>(test.length());
for (int index = 0; index < test.length(); index++) {

    char value = test.charAt(index);
    if (Character.isDigit(value)) {

        listValues.add(Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(value)));

    }


}
```

Now, you could use a `StringBuilder` instead of a `List`, but this was what came off my head.

Next, you need to sum them

```
for (int index = 0; index < listValues.size(); index++) {

    sum += (listValues.get(index) * (test.length() - index - 1));

}
```

And I ended up with something like

```
(4 * 6) + (2 * 5) + (9 * 4) + (3 * 3) + (2 * 2) + (5 * 1)
= 88
```

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson hay, didn't say it was great ;) - the test String was using the correct formula, the actually calculation wasn't, thanks for noticing, you've past the answerer is a dummy test ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Sorry for late reply.I was unwell.
Thanks for you help.I'm implementing the algorithm for validation.I will explain it briefly (4 * 6) + (2 * 5) + (9 * 4) + (3 * 3) + (2 * 2)%11=6 and 11-6=5 should match the digit after "-" that is 5.Again Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The calculate it the same way as you do in mathematics and just about any other language

```
4*10000 + 2*1000 + 9*100 + 3*10 + 2*1 - 5*1
```

Works in Fortran, C, C++, C#, Scala, ....

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, there is no reason to make it a String if you're looking for a sum...  I'll try to help you out by giving you a lead: You would need to use the modulus operator (%), in order to access the right-most digit of the integer on its own.  After doing that, divide the integer by 10 in order to remove the right-most number, and then use the % operator again in order to gain access to the next digit.  If you put this idea into a loop and make some small modifications, it should do exactly what you're looking for.

Basically, you're trying to add each digit separately to a total.  In your case, you want to be multiplying each digit by another number before you add it to the total.  Shouldn't be hard to figure out.  Hope this helps!